# Set a value for every item except the item passed Immutable JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm starting with ImmutableJS, i have the following redux:

```js
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

import {
    SET_MODAL_VISIBLE
} from './constants';

const initialState = fromJS({
  loginModal: 'none',
  registerModal: 'none',
  passwordModal: 'none',
});

function modalReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_MODAL_VISIBLE:
      return state
        .set(action.modal, 'block');
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default modalReducer;
```

How can i back all state`s item for 'none' except the "action.modal" ? I know that i can use

```
return initialState
       .set(action.modal, 'block');
```

But use initialState is not good for me because the state will be more items that I do not want to go back to the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume action.model is a string so you can get all keys from your state and set them to "none" except the action.model key using reduce:

```
[...state.keys()].reduce(
  (state,key)=>
    (key===action.model)
      ? state.set(key,"block")
      : state.set(key,"none"),
  state
);
```

Comment: why not just use map?

Comment: @gy134340 map is to have a list of 'a turn to a list ob 'b. Reduce is to have a list of 'a turn to any type (single or list). The list of keys (string) is turned into one immutable object. Not sure how you'd use map for this and if it's even appropriate.